# Round A List Of Decimal Lists

Tags: c#, linq, rounding

I'm trying to find a shorter way of rounding each element in a `List<List<decimal>>`, and wondering if there's a way I can shorten it with Linq?

I've tried several ways, such as this

```
List<List<Decimal>> masterList = dataSet
.Select(x => x.Values)
.ToList()
.Select(i => Math.Round(i, 2));  
/// THIS GIVES AN EXCEPTION (CANNOT CONVERT FROM System.Collections.Generic.List<decimal> to 'double'
```

This is my current way of doing it?

```
List<List<Decimal>> masterList = dataSet.Select(x => x.Values).ToList();

foreach (var list in masterList)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = Math.Round(list[i], 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Decimal.Round`, not `Math.Round`, to do the job:

```
masterList = masterList.Select(
    x => x.Select(y => Decimal.Round(y, 2)).ToList()
    ).ToList();
```

**Edited** with the number of decimals (2). Also, the problem seems to be in the `LINQ` statement instead of the use of `Math.Round` or `Decimal.Round`.

`Decimal.Round` is my preference for `decimal` case though, especially when the `decimal` value needs to be converted to the shortest `int`. The format is very handy: `Decimal.Round(val)`

Comment: He can us Math.Round too, he just used it on List<decimal> instead of using on decimal

Comment: @S.Petrosov ah yes, just notice that there is `Math.Round(dec,MidpointRounding.ToEven)` option too.

Comment: @BrendanGooden - This answer doesn't give the result you're looking for. It needs `Decimal.Round(y, 2)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity correct I already picked that up, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can do it using LINQ:

```
List<List<decimal>> list= new List<List<decimal>>();
list.Add(new List<decimal>(){ 1.501M,2.231M,3M});
list.Add(new List<decimal>(){ 4.505M,5M,3M});
list.Add(new List<decimal>(){ 1M,7M,8M});
var result = list.Select(x=>x.Select(y=>Math.Round(y,2)).ToList()).ToList();
foreach(var a in result)
{
    foreach(var b in a)
    {
        Console.Write(b + "\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```